# Can I signal an error in HTTP after the data was downloaded?

Tags: http, tcp, http2, false-positive, http3

I want the following:

- Stream to the client a (possibly big) file through HTTP and **after** the file was already fully streamed to client (possibly) signal to the client an error (such as 404 not found or 500 internal server error).

In HTTP 1.x this seems impossible: The errors are signaled in headers that are streamed before the body.

Maybe, it's possible in HTTP/2? How?

I could just interrupt the HTTP TCP connection, but in this case the client may assume that the error was not 404 or 500 (in my case it means erroneous file content that needs to be wiped out by the client) but a partially downloaded file and next time may try to use `Range:` to append more data to (incorrect) downloaded data.

I know it can be done by creating my own file format, but I want to deliver to the client the file as is and use *standard* HTTP errors.

Comment: That's because I know whether the data is correct by a checksum that can be calculated only after streaming finishes.

Comment: If the checksum failed, I want to interrupt the current streaming and start streaming anew, ideally without the client doing anything "custom", e.g. I could do it using a HTTP redirect (to the same URL?) sent to the client **after** failed streaming.

Comment: Maybe re-streaming could be possible on TCP level? That possibly may be a good addition to TCP standard, but it may increase network loads if abused...

Comment: ... or not increase.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a partial solution:

When starting the first streaming, return:

```
203 Non-Authoritative Information
...
Warning: 110 - "Response is Stale"
Expires: 0
```

or

```
203 Non-Authoritative Information
...
Warning: 111 - "Revalidation Failed"
Expires: 0
```

(Should it be 110 or 111?)

Then on the subsequent steams from my cache return

```
304 Not Modified
...
```

(to my downstream proxy) if there were no checksum error or just stream it again from the cache.

So the proxy will give to the browser some document indicating it as expired on the first try and re-download on the second try if there was an error.